# Why don't Direct2D and DirectWrite use traditional COM objects?

Tags: c#, .net, com, direct2d, directwrite

I'm toying with a little 2D game engine in C# and decided to use Direct2D and DirectWrite for rendering. I know there's the Windows API Code Pack and SlimDX, but I'd really like to dig in and write an interface from scratch. I'm trying to do it without Managed C++, but Direct2D and DirectWrite don't appear to use traditional COM objects. They define interfaces that derive from `IUnknown`, but there appears to be no way to actually use them from C# with COM interop. There are IIDs in `d2d1.h`, but no CLSID.

Of course, I'm really new to COM interop, so perhaps I'm just missing something. Can someone shed some light on this situation?

Comment: Check this post: http://www.itcommunity.ru/blogs/nesteruk/archive/2009/09/14/76753.aspx
It still involves some C++. And you're not looking for COM, but to load dlls and wrap the signatures using DllImport

Comment: Because DirectX was geared around C/C++ from way back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it. You can't create the objects directly, but `d2d1.dll` contains an export called `D2D1CreateFactory` that returns an `ID2DFactory` interface. Using this, you can implement a Direct2D wrapper without Managed C++.

```
public static class Direct2D1Util {
    public const string IID_ID2D1Factory =
        "06152247-6f50-465a-9245-118bfd3b6007";

    [DllImport("d2d1.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    private static extern object D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE factoryType,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid,
        D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS pFactoryOptions);

    public static ID2D1Factory CreateFactory() {
        D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS opts = new D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS();
        object factory = D2D1CreateFactory(
            D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE.D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
            new Guid(IID_ID2D1Factory), opts);
        return (ID2D1Factory)factory;
    }
}
```

I won't include all of the types, because they're all defined in `d2d1.h`, but here's how to use the code to get a factory:

```
ID2DFactory factory = Direct2D1Util.CreateFactory();
```

Make sure your `ID2DFactory` interface has the appropriate `Guid` and `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)` attributes.

Comment: The signature of D2D1CreateFactory is

    HRESULT WINAPI
    D2D1CreateFactory(
        _In_ D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE factoryType,
        _In_ REFIID riid,
        _In_opt_ CONST D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS *pFactoryOptions,
        _Out_ void **ppIFactory
        );

How can this be declared as a method in C# that returns a object? Because the ppIFactory is the last argument of the function? But why?

Answer (score 6):

The "Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework" has managed libraries that allow access to Direct2D and DirectWrite.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

### Update

Whilst the DirectX wrappers are written in managed C++, they produce managed libraries. By the looks of things these can be used from C#. There look to be plenty of examples included in the download that do exactly this i.e. use the managed C++ Direct wrapper libraries from C#.

Using Windows 7 features in my own C# application would be very nice, so I am currently installing the Window7 SDK (so that I can build the managed C++ DirectX solution) and will give the whole thing a bash.

I am following the instructions at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/msaleh/archive/2009/08/25/introducing-directx-features-of-windows-api-code-pack.aspx

## Update 2

Following the instructions in the above link I got the managed C++ libraries compiled and you can indeed use them from C# very easily.

Now I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but are you just looking at some way of using Direct2D and DirectWrite from C#, or does it have to be COM or P\Invoke.

I would very much doubt there would be a COM wrapper, as it's a mismatched technology. COM is not really well designed for the sort of high-frequency method call patterns that you get in Graphics programming - it is way too slow.

If you really want to do P\Invoke you could always look at the DirectX header files (in the Windows 7 SDK) and use a tool to create all your P\Invoke call stubs, e.g.

http://www.pinvoker.com/

That would probably be a major PITA though to develop a wrapper this way.

Comment: Please read my question. I stated that I have checked the Windows API Code Pack and SlimDX, but they are written in Managed C++, whereas I would like to do this with pure C# and COM Interop/PInvoke.

Comment: My apologies, didn't scan the question correctly. I really should get some sleep...

Answer (score 2):

There's a project on codeplex that provides managed wrappers for Direct2D. I have no idea if it's any good, but most likely the source code will help you get started.

http://direct2dsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it's written in Managed C++. I'd really like to do this using COM interop direct from C#.

Comment: COM interop is used to use COM objects from managed code.  Are you wanting to find COM wrappers that essentially P/Invoke for you so that you can generate interops for them?  If so, I can't imagine what kind of performance you are expecting....